# Exclude Null from left jon

Tags: sql, left-join

I have joined 2 table - Left Join

```
Select a.Invoice,
       b.Prodict
From table1 a
left join table2 b
on a.Id = b.Id
```

[image]

What I am trying to is if 1 invoice has 2 or more product then exclude the Null value, if only has Null value, then keep Null.
Thank you so much
Blessed.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please, provide some [sample data](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) [in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You seem to have `NULL` values in the data.  I would suggest filtering them out in the `LEFT JOIN` itself:

```
Select a.Invoice,
       b.Product
From table1 a left join
     table2 b
     on a.Id = b.Id and b.Product is not null;
```

The only `NULL`s will be those generated by the `LEFT JOIN`:

The only issue with this solution is if you want *other* columns from `b` and there is one matching row that is `NULL`.  With this solution, those other columns would be `NULL`.

If this is your actual problem, ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to filter the second table not to include nulls

```
Select a.Invoice,
       b.Prodict
From table1 a
left join table2 b
on a.Id = b.Id and b.Prodict is not null
```

Comment: If I set Product is not null it would exclude some Invoice only have Null values. For example like Invoice number 4

Comment: @Hanry_Lou No, it won't :) Just try yourselves. Note that filter is in join condition, not in where condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify if there's any non-null `Product` row in the `table2` for Invoice with `null` in `Product` column.

If your DBMS has analytical functions then you can use it:

> ```
> with table1 as (
>   select 1 as id, 'A' as Invoice union all
>   select 2 as id, 'B' as Invoice union all
>   select 3 as id, 'B' as Invoice union all
>   select 4 as id, 'C' as Invoice
> )
> , table2 as (
>   select 1 as id, 'AA' as Product union all
>   select 1 as id, 'AB' as Product union all
>   select 2 as id, 'BA' as Product union all
>   select 2 as id, NULL as Product union all
>   select 2 as id, 'BB' as Product
> )
> , find_null as (
> Select
>   a.Invoice,
>   b.Product,
>   /*Check if NULL is here*/
>   max(case when b.Product is null then 1 end) over(partition by a.Invoice) as has_null,
>   /*Count not null values*/
>   count(b.Product) over(partition by a.Invoice) as item_cnt
> From table1 a
>   left join table2 b
>     on a.Id = b.Id
> )
> select invoice, product
> from find_null
> where not (
>   has_null = 1
>   and item_cnt > 0
>   /*Exclude null where there's a row without null*/
>   and product is null
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> invoice | product
> :------ | :------
> A       | AA     
> A       | AB     
> B       | BA     
> B       | BB     
> C       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=369056be50b4fde283a060fbfad44210)*

Or the same with `EXISTS` which is valid for any SQL database:

> ```
> with table1 as (
>   select 1 as id, 'A' as Invoice union all
>   select 2 as id, 'B' as Invoice union all
>   select 3 as id, 'B' as Invoice union all
>   select 4 as id, 'C' as Invoice
> )
> , table2 as (
>   select 1 as id, 'AA' as Product union all
>   select 1 as id, 'AB' as Product union all
>   select 2 as id, 'BA' as Product union all
>   select 2 as id, NULL as Product union all
>   select 2 as id, 'BB' as Product
> )
> Select
>   a.Invoice,
>   b.Product
> From table1 a
>   left join table2 b
>     on a.Id = b.Id
> where not exists (
>   select 1
>   from table1 f1
>     join table2 f2
>       on f1.id = f2.id
>   where f1.invoice = a.invoice
>     and f2.product is not null
>     and b.Product is null
>   
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Invoice | Product
> :------ | :------
> A       | AA     
> A       | AB     
> B       | BA     
> B       | BB     
> C       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=8fbb77e6ddb360786c08afd19ab1bf2c)*

Comment: My table 1 has 450M records, after join it returns 15M record. It is difficult to keep track with each one.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` does not remove anything from the source on the left side, so I cannot imagine it can reduce the number of rows produced. As long as it is not clear what is the relationship between `Invoice`, `Id` and `Product` and there's no any DBMS tag I've added this generic answer. Otherwise there're good and short answers above